# Binomial equation development

Tags: algebra-precalculus

can I assume that $\frac{a((a+1)^n-1)}{a^2}$ = $\frac{a^n}{a}$ ?

How does the $1$ develops through the binomial equation?

thanks.

Comment: But $\frac{a((a+1)^n - 1)}{a^2} = \frac{(a+1)^n - 1}{a} \neq \frac{a^n}{a}$ ...

Comment: my point is, how can I get rid of the $1$ inside the $(a+1)^n$?

Comment: @MattiP. I need to show that $\frac{a((a+1)^n-1)}{a^2}$ equals an Integer

Comment: @Eran19978 So what has happened here is a classic case of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why didn't you ask about that fraction being an integer in the first place?

Comment: @Arthur It's a part of an induction question that I need to prove. I was wondering if my math was right but apparently it isn't lol..

Comment: @Arthur I needed to prove that for each $a,n\in\mathbb{N}$ $(a+1)^n -na -1$ devided by $a^2$ provided an integer

Comment: @Eran19978 Well, that's a bit different from your original question, but the approach in my answer should work equally well there.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot assume that. Insert, for instance, $a = 1$. Then
$$
\frac{a((a+1)^n-1)}{a^2} = 2^n - 1\\
\frac{a^n}{a} = 1
$$
and those are quite different.

As for how the $1$ develops through the binomial equation, that's quite simple: Use the binomial theorem on $(a+1)^n$, and leave the rest completely unchanged, and you get:
$$
\frac{a((a+1)^n-1)}{a^2} = \frac{a\left(\left(a^n + \binom n1a^{n-1} + \binom n2a^{n-2} + \cdots + \binom n{n-1}a + 1\right)-1\right)}{a^2}
$$
And from there you can simplify a bit.

Comment: Could I argue that $\frac{a\left(\left(a^n + \binom n1a^{n-1} + \binom n2a^{n-2} + \cdots + \binom n{n-1}a + 1\right)-1\right)}{a^2}$ provies an Integer?

Comment: because I can reduce the $1$s

Comment: @Eran19978 you can reduce the 1s, yes. And after that, is there more you can reduce?

Comment: Only the $a's$ no ?

Comment: @Eran19978 Which a's? What is left afterwards?

Comment: The outer a in the dominator with the a in the numerator?

Comment: @Eran19978 And what are you left with after reducing the $1$'s and those $a$'s?

Comment: What is left is some kind of sum that I can't express, care to point it out?

Comment: What is left is $\frac{a^n + \binom n1a^{n-1} + \cdots + \binom n2 a^2 + \binom n1 a}{a}$. You're one simplification away from the answer now.

Comment: Divide each component by a. Then what do I get?

Comment: @Eran19978 A fraction with a $1$ in its denominator. What was it you were ultimately after again?

Comment: I need to prove by induction that for any natural $a,n$ $(a+1)^n -na -1$ divided by $a^2$ provides an integer. But I'm thinking now that my way of proof isn't right.